# Can filtered transactions be used for validation consensus

Tags: corda

Is it possible to minimize the breach of confidential information when "walking the chain" as part of validation consensus by using the Merkle-tree filtered transaction technique?

Answer (score 0):

We would need more information to continue the conversation. Also, you could join the #architecture channel at our slack @http://slack.corda.net/ to chat with our core engineers and our community developers.